# Boost: How to print/convert posix_time::ptime in milliseconds from Epoch?

Tags: boost, time, posix, epoch, milliseconds

I am having trouble converting `posix_time::ptime` to a timestamp represented by `time_t` or `posix_time::milliseconds`, or any other appropriate type which can be easily printed (from Epoch).

I actually need just to print the timestamp represented by the `posix_time::ptime` in milliseconds, so if there is an easy way to print in that format, I don't actually need the conversion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code will print the number of milliseconds since 1941-12-07T00:00:00. Obviously, you can choose whatever epoch suits your need.

```
void print_ptime_in_ms_from_epoch(const boost::posix_time::ptime& pt)
  {
    using boost::posix_time::ptime;
    using namespace boost::gregorian;
    std::cout << (pt-ptime(date(1941, Dec, 7))).total_milliseconds() << "\n";
  }
```

Comment: Worth noting here that the timezone offset information found in pt will affect the outcome. For example, if pt was grabbed with microsec_clock::universal_time(), you will get a different answer than if you did microsec_clock::local_time().